# Pagination Error for Datatables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

[image]

can some teach me how to fixed this error in table. . pagination did not work. .

Comment: Share your code, so that we can understand where its going wrong.

Comment: Possibly you forgot to include CSS files for Bootstrap, see CSS tab in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).